# Which domain to specify on dropbox dropin app with github pages

Tags: github, dropbox, dropbox-api, github-pages

I'm using the dropbox's dropin javascript api and created a git repository under the gh-pages branch so that i can use github pages. Problem is I'm confused which domain to add as my Drop-ins domain, which specifies "If using Drop-ins on a website, the domain of that site."
I've tried to add my github-pages url **"http://username.github.io/repo_name"**.
But i get an error stating :-

> "The domain name you entered is invalid"

and the button's response states :-

> {"error": "Origin does not match any app domain"}

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give some code to examine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enter just the domain: `username.github.io`